# How to get exact solution to Sod shock tube test?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, computational-physics, shock-waves

I wrote a program in Fortran which calculates Sod shock tube numerically. Now I want to compare it with exact (analytical) solution, but I don't know how to get it.

Can I find it somewhere or do I have to write a new program which calculates it? If it's the latter,  where can I find the equations I need?

Comment: Isn't this just on Wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the [Sod shock tube](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sod_shock_tube), there are 5 states, two of which come from initial conditions (states I & V in the linked Wiki entry). Two of the remaining 3 can be calculated with relative ease given the linked Wikipedia entry; the most difficult state (III) requires a root solver to find the value of the pressure.

What's not covered in the Wiki entry is state II, which is the rarefaction wave region. In this region, we have that:
\begin{align}
u_{2}(x)&=\frac{2}{\gamma+1}\cdot\left(c_1+\frac{\left(x-x_\text{mid}\right)}{t}\right)\\
\rho_{2}(x)&=\rho_1\cdot\left(1-\frac{\gamma-1}{2}\cdot\frac{u_{2}(x)}{c_1}\right)^{2/(\gamma-1)}\\
P_{2}(x)&=P_1\cdot\left(1-\frac{\gamma-1}{2}\cdot\frac{u_{2}(x)}{c_1}\right)^{2\gamma/(\gamma-1)}
\end{align}
where $x_\text{mid}$ is the point that divides the two states (often taken to be 0.5 with boundaries at 0 & 1), $t$ the time since the simulation started and $c_1$ the speed of sound in state I (the left state)--note that this assumes that the left state is the over-pressure region--all other terms take their normal meaning.

Building a function or two to find the states should be pretty straight-forward, once the above is known.

Comment: I know Wikipedia mentions it, but these equations are for a calorically perfect gas. Thermally perfect or other EOS's (stiffened gas, Mie-Gruneisen, etc.) are also possible, but require more complex iterative solvers in the various states. We've still called them "Sod shock tubes." I think shallow-water equation folks call it a dam breaking problem.

Comment: Thank you! I found pretty straight-forward manual also here: https://www3.nd.edu/~gtryggva/CFD-Course2017/Lecture-10-2017.pdf  but I am not sure about what 's' is (on page 3, right upper slide). Also, by the iteration they talk about on page 2, left lower slide, do they mean fixed point iteration? I am pretty new to this area, so I am not sure.

Comment: I meant 'page 2, right lower slide', sorry.

Comment: @Andrej I'll have to read it (on mobile currently), but generally any root finding algorithm is considered *iterative*.

Comment: @Andrej The value of the pressure in region 3 depends on itself (i.e., $P_3=f(P_3,...)$), so any iterative method (fixed point, bisection, Brent, etc) will work, that's what they mean with that statement.

Comment: Thanks, I will try it. And do you know what that 's' is? It has no index and is used for calculation in expansion fan. (page 3, right upper slide)

Comment: @Andrej I believe it to be the position along the axis with $x$ the shock location. Note also that the functions do not fully line up with what I have (e.g., the power of $2\gamma/(\gamma-1)$ for density, the $p_4=p_4(\cdots)$), so you may be wary of typos & want to look at other resources online.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder what is unclear about this answer that warrants a downvote 5 years later?

Answer (score -1):

@Andrej This is great question, @Kyle thank you for your response.
I combine the notes which @Andrej mentioned in the comments with @Kyle's rarefaction wave region to produce a python code which produces the analytic solution. As @Kyle points out there is potentially a typo in the notes so it takes effort to accomplish this combination.

```
# Libraries
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import newton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Function to find the roots of!
def f(P, pL, pR, cL, cR, gg):
    a = (gg-1)*(cR/cL)*(P-1) 
    b = np.sqrt( 2*gg*(2*gg + (gg+1)*(P-1) ) )
    return P - pL/pR*( 1 - a/b )**(2.*gg/(gg-1.))

# Analtyic Sol to Sod Shock
def SodShockAnalytic(rL, uL, pL, rR, uR, pR, xs, x0, T, gg):
    # rL, uL, pL, rR, uR, pR : Initial conditions of the Reimann problem 
    # xs: position array (e.g. xs = [0,dx,2*dx,...,(Nx-1)*dx])
    # x0: THIS IS AN INDEX! the array index where the interface sits.
    # T: the desired solution time
    # gg: adiabatic constant 1.4=7/5 for a 3D diatomic gas
    dx = xs[1];
    Nx = len(xs)
    v_analytic = np.zeros((3,Nx),dtype='float64')

    # compute speed of sound
    cL = np.sqrt(gg*pL/rL); 
    cR = np.sqrt(gg*pR/rR);
    # compute P
    P = newton(f, 0.5, args=(pL, pR, cL, cR, gg), tol=1e-12);

    # compute region positions right to left
    # region R
    c_shock = uR + cR*np.sqrt( (gg-1+P*(gg+1)) / (2*gg) )
    x_shock = x0 + int(np.floor(c_shock*T/dx))
    v_analytic[0,x_shock-1:] = rR
    v_analytic[1,x_shock-1:] = uR
    v_analytic[2,x_shock-1:] = pR
    
    # region 2
    alpha = (gg+1)/(gg-1)
    c_contact = uL + 2*cL/(gg-1)*( 1-(P*pR/pL)**((gg-1.)/2/gg) )
    x_contact = x0 + int(np.floor(c_contact*T/dx))
    v_analytic[0,x_contact:x_shock-1] = (1 + alpha*P)/(alpha+P)*rR
    v_analytic[1,x_contact:x_shock-1] = c_contact
    v_analytic[2,x_contact:x_shock-1] = P*pR
    
    # region 3
    r3 = rL*(P*pR/pL)**(1/gg);
    p3 = P*pR;
    c_fanright = c_contact - np.sqrt(gg*p3/r3)
    x_fanright = x0 + int(np.ceil(c_fanright*T/dx))
    v_analytic[0,x_fanright:x_contact] = r3;
    v_analytic[1,x_fanright:x_contact] = c_contact;
    v_analytic[2,x_fanright:x_contact] = P*pR;
    
    # region 4
    c_fanleft = -cL
    x_fanleft = x0 + int(np.ceil(c_fanleft*T/dx))
    u4 = 2 / (gg+1) * (cL + (xs[x_fanleft:x_fanright]-xs[x0])/T )
    v_analytic[0,x_fanleft:x_fanright] = rL*(1 - (gg-1)/2.*u4/cL)**(2/(gg-1));
    v_analytic[1,x_fanleft:x_fanright] = u4;
    v_analytic[2,x_fanleft:x_fanright] = pL*(1 - (gg-1)/2.*u4/cL)**(2*gg/(gg-1));

    # region L
    v_analytic[0,:x_fanleft] = rL
    v_analytic[1,:x_fanleft] = uL
    v_analytic[2,:x_fanleft] = pL

    return v_analytic

# Physics
gg=1.4  # gamma = C_v / C_p = 7/5 for ideal gas
rL, uL, pL =  1.0,  0.0, 1; 
rR, uR, pR = 0.125, 0.0, .1;

# Set Disretization
Nx = 100
X = 1.
dx = X/(Nx-1)
xs = np.linspace(0,X,Nx)
x0 = Nx//2
T = 0.2

analytic = SodShockAnalytic(rL, uL, pL, rR, uR, pR, xs, x0, T, gg)

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,3,figsize=(8,2), layout='constrained')
axs[0].set_title("Density")
axs[0].plot(xs,analytic[0].T)
axs[1].set_title("Velocity")
axs[1].plot(xs,analytic[1].T)
axs[1].set_yticks([0.,.2,.4,.6,.8,1.],['','','','','',''])
axs[2].set_title("Pressure")
axs[2].plot(xs,analytic[2].T)
axs[2].set_yticks([0.,.2,.4,.6,.8,1.],['','','','','',''])
for i in range(3):
    axs[i].set_xlim([0.,1.])
    axs[i].set_ylim([-.05,1.05])
```

This produces the following plots for me!
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLYaa.png